# How do I increase scale of DB2 query results in SQuirreL?

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, db2, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to take a column of historical time-stamps and out of it create a column containing the number of years between the current time-stamp and and the historical one, *under the assumption that there are 365.25 days in a year* .

Thus far I have been able to accomplish this using the following query:
select column1 as CLASS, column2 as DATE_CREATED, TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,char(SYSDATE-column2)/365.25 AS YearsDiff from DELIVERYCLASS order by YearsDiff DESC;

The problem however is that the results of the query show the number of years only in the scale of two. That is, I only get the number of years up to the hundredth decimal point. This is not good enough. I need it to be scaled out to at least 10 digits.

I have links to two screenshots, one by conducting the query as above and one without dividing by 365.25.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[without divide by 365.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Eiu.png)
[with divide by 365.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8daHf.png)

Comment: Looks like the client (SQuirrel) problem; according to the [arithmetic operator result rules](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-2-10&lang=en) the actual result data type should be `DECIMAL(31,18)`.

Comment: You do know that `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is going to assume 365 days/year, right?  So if you have exactly a 1-year difference, your current math will return an amount **less** than 1.  Even for leap years.  You'd be better of using [`DAYS(...)`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000789.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-37) on each and using the difference.  What are you using this for, anyways?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a SQirreL setting.
Check out Global Preferences -> Data Type Controls -> Float, real, Double,... 
And set your required number of digits....

I have added the screenshot to clarify it

[image: Screenshot]